# Strange running times in C++ loops

Tags: c++, loops, optimization

So, I'm writing a program, where optimization is a key factor. However: during optimization, I notice a function I considered relatively simple, was taking way too long to run. Especially since, in comparison, a much more difficult function is taking way shorter.

[Whole Relevant section](https://pastebin.com/PPaE08Nk)

```
// Simple function

int get_chunk_index(std::vector<Chunk> chunks, int x, int y) {
    glm::vec3 target = glm::vec3(x * 40, 0, y * 40);
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
        if (chunks[i].trans.GetPos() == target) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// End simple function
```

[image: Time in function]

If you would like any more functions, feel free to ask, but it is quite a large program, so I can't include *everything* here.

PS: *chunks* is only ever about 0->40 in size.

Comment: Try taking `chunks.size()` out of the loop, by assigning it to a variable. And what does `getPos()` do?

Comment: Have you tried changing `std::vector<Chunk>` to `const std::vector<Chunk>&`? This should save a little bit by allowing the deep copy to be removed.

Comment: Linking to pastebin is poor style, since that is not under the control of this website, and you or pastebin itself may decide to remove it later. Post a standalone sample that can reproduce the problem you describe [in the process, you may find that you solve the problem]

Comment: Additionally, the distribution of the input of things in the vector directly relates to the running time of any instance of the function -- the function's running time stability is thus directly connected to the possible probability distribution of input data.

Comment: @Barmar getpos literally just returns the private member pos from the transform class

Comment: Use a profiler to see precisely where the time is being spent.

Comment: @VermillionAzure I think you may be onto something with the reference. Chunk is a large class. Trying now.

Comment: @VermillionAzure It was indeed the deep copy. It now runs at about 0.0000006s, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few simple options.

1)   `chunks` is being passed by value, which creates a complete copy of the vector being passed.   Try passing by `const` reference  (i.e. `const std::vector<Chunk> &chunk`) instead.

2)    Rather than passing `x` and `y`, and creating a `glm::vec3` (whatever that is - it's non-standard) from them, change the function to accept a `glm::vec3` by reference.   This forces the caller to create the object, but also allows the caller to control updating of it (rather than recreating a new object every time).

3)   Take the evaluation of `chunks.size()` out of the loop, and use preincrement (won't create a temporary) rather than post-increment.

```
std::size_t size = chunks.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (chunks[i].trans.GetPos() == target)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

4)  Consider using iterators rather than array indexing.

```
std::vector<Chunk>::const_iterator i, begin = chunks.begin(), end = chunks.end();

for (i = begin; i != end; ++i)
   if (i->trans.GetPos() == target) return std::distance(begin, i);
```

or  (C++11 and later)

```
for (const auto &i : chunks)
{
    if (i.trans.GetPos() == target) return std::distance(chunks.begin(), i);
}
```

5)   Instead of passing the vector, pass its `begin` and `end` iterators.   That will allow more simplification of the loop.

6)    Check what the `getPos()` function being called is doing, and optimise that.

7)   Do your timing measurements with optimisation turned on, and do them across a large number of calls of the function.  Performance measurements of individual function calls don't mean much in practice (the jitter in other things that affect performance will dominate your measurements).

Comment: Just a note on the "pre-increment": all modern compilers can optimise away the generation of such temporary values in all but the most convoluted and complex cases. [I personally would use C++11 range loops as per 4(b), but that's regardless of "temporaries"]

Comment: For basic types, yeah. But not necessarily for user-defined types which supply overloaded pre and post increment (most people doing that cause those operators to have "normal" semantics) which means a temporary to hold the previous value of a post-increment - which a compiler can't necessarily elide unless it has visibility of definition of the overloaded operator at the call site. Although a vector's iterators CAN be (and often are, in practice) pointers, there is nothing preventing them from being a user-defined type with overloaded operators.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being simply the deep copy, as Chunk is quite a large file, and I didn't notice the copy.

Working Code :

```
// Simple function

int get_chunk_index(std::vector<Chunk>& chunks, int x, int y) {
    glm::vec3 target = glm::vec3(x * 40, 0, y * 40);
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
        if (chunks[i].trans.GetPos() == target) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// End simple function
```